# How to aggregate akka-http routes using a trait?

Tags: scala, dynamic, akka-http, spray-routing

I am trying to aggregate routes using a trait at runtime, so far I have

```
object SMController {
  def aggregateRoutes(actorSystem: ActorSystem): List[Route] = {
    val runtimeMirror = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
    val reflections = new Reflections("com.example.api")
    val subclasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(classOf[Routable])
    val routesList = new ListBuffer[Route]()

    for (i <- subclasses) {
      val module = runtimeMirror.staticModule(i.getName)
      val obj = runtimeMirror.reflectModule(module)
      val someTrait: Routable = obj.instance.asInstanceOf[Routable]
      routesList += someTrait.getAllRoutes(actorSystem)
    }

    routesList.toList
  }
}
```

obviously above code doesn't work as the List of items cannot be passed to `Http().bindAndHandle`.

So my question is,  how can I parse the `List[Routes]` to a `Http().bindAndHandle` accepts or how can I dynamically load routes from subclasses of `Routable`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**foldLeft:**
I have managed to foldLeft the routes and coalesce all the routes, as follows

```
val routes = SMController.aggregateRoutes(system)
val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(
        routes.tail.foldLeft(routes.head)((a, b) => a ~ b), "localhost", 8080)
```

**reduceLeft:**

```
routes.reduceLeft(_ ~ _)
```